# Measuring large distances when all layers are in decimal degrees using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, distance

I just developed a distance matrix between various points across Canada in QGIS. The distances produced are in decimal degrees, and I would like to view them in metric. I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: can you re-project your data to something like Albers Equal Area? That would give you distances in something more meaningful

Comment: An equidistant conic might be slightly better but still won't give very accurate distances. Depending on how much accuracy you want, you might need geodesic, or possibly great circle, distances instead. I couldn't find quickly a solution for qgis.

Comment: Save your data into PostGIS as geography and query distances with SQL. Spatialite can also calculate geodesic lengths.

Comment: My projection is NAD83(CSRS) / Statistics Canada Lambert, as the data I am using are from Statistics Canada. I thought that conical projections would allow me to measure in metric, but everything is still coming up in degrees.